# Spring Boot: How to generate unique username based on name during registration of user

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, unique

I have spring boot application and simple UserService which is called by controller. During registration I want to generate unique username (that is not present is database) based on name.
For example, if name is Jim username should be name + random number (Jim342123).

Basically it is the same idea how twitter generates username.

User can input same name Jim and in very rare cases username can be same (Jim342123).

[UserSerivce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xX1B.png)

How to avoid generating same username or how to handle if same username will be generated?

What is best way to achieve this?

What is best way to implement generateUsername() method?

I tried something like this but I don't think it is good solution.

[Bad Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wjezy.png)

Comment: could append a UUID to the name or a similarly unlikely to repeat system

Comment: Generate random suffix, composed of random numbers(for example), append it to name, check if taken. If your random generation algorithm is good enough, you should have low collisions. You may want to consider indexing the username in db, to make the lookup faster.

Comment: Jim`<current_nano_second>`_`<random_number>`: current nano second will always increase, while you random number will be random. Quite impossible to have the same user name that way, I think.

Comment: Why generate the username at all?  If the user just enters their email address, it will be unique.

Comment: Easiest way - concatenate random number -> try to save it to DB (unique column) -> handle duplicate exception -> rerun same flow till success.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask]

Answer (score 0):

From a architectural point of view: a microservice who generate and store all used usernames in a database might be a good approach. It is called the single-source-of-truth principle.

But do we need this? It depends on the expected amount of users. Do you expect about 5.000.000.000.000.000.000.000.000.000.000.000 users? A uuid is a good bet. Otherwise I would take the size of the users-table. If Jim is the 20th user, his generated username might be Jim20.

No need for random numbers, right?